# ckeditor.js:21 [CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-destroy-iframe in angular2

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I have use angular 4 and ckeditor 4.6.2. 
If I am go to next component show this error :-

```
[CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-destroy-iframe. 
[CKEDITOR] For more information about this error go to http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_errors-section-editor-destroy-iframe
```

Component.ts :-

```
ckeConfig = "";
this.ckeConfig = {
   height: 500,
   width: '60%',
   allowedContent: false,
   fullPage : true,
   toolbar: [
       { name: "styles", items: ['Format', 'Font', 'FontSize', "-", "TextColor", "BGColor"] },
       { name: "basicstyles", items: ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "RemoveFormat"] },
       "/",
       { name: "justify", items: ["JustifyLeft", "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyBlock"] },
       { name: "paragraph", items: ["NumberedList", "BulletedList", "-", "Outdent", "Indent", "-", "Blockquote"] },
       { name: "links", items: ["Link", "Unlink"] },
       { name: "insert", items: ["Image", "Table", "HorizontalRule", "Smiley","SpecialChar"] },
       { name: "document", items: ["Source"] },
   ]
 };
```

Component.html :-

```
<ckeditor
  [config]="ckeConfig"
  [(ngModel)] = "content"
  debounce="1000"
  >
  <button  md-raised-button type="button" routerLink= "/all" routerLinkAction="active" color="primary">Cancel</button>
```

If click on cancel button go to next component then show this error in console. Tell us how to solve this error?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

> need to use `divarea plugin` or `inline mode`

reference: https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/24